# Initiate ajax function and process form separately when HTML form is sent

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I have a HTML form shown here:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="80" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Send a reply..."></textarea>
 <input type="hidden" id="conversation_id" name="conversation_id" value="<? echo $co_conversation_id; ?>">
 <input type="hidden" id="sarssystem" name="sarssystem" value="<? echo $sarssystem; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group" align="right">

<div class="btn-group" align="left" style="float:left">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="messages.php?convoid=<? echo $co_conversation_id; ?>&del=check">Delete Conversation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Visit Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Report User</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Change Display Photo</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Cancel</button>
  <button type="submit" id="reply" name="reply" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Send Message</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Which is meant to initiate this PHP script on the same page:

```
if(isset($_POST['reply'])){
    $user_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $conversation_id = $_POST['conversation_id'];
    $sarssystem = $_POST['sarssystem'];

    if(isset($sarssystem)){
    if($sarssystem == 1){

$usr_message = str_replace("'","\\'",$message);

mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ap_messages (message_id, message, sender_id, time_sent, time_read, conversation_id) 
VALUES ('','$usr_message','$user_id', NOW(), NOW(), '$conversation_id')");

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ap_conversations SET time = NOW() WHERE conversation_id = '$conversation_id'");

    } else {

        $reply = str_replace("'","\\'",$message); 


mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ap_messages (message_id, message, sender_id, time_sent, time_read, conversation_id) 
VALUES ('','$reply','$user_id', NOW(), '', '$conversation_id')");   

    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ap_conversations SET time = NOW() WHERE conversation_id = '$conversation_id'");

    }
    } else {

        $reply = str_replace("'","\\'",$message); 


mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ap_messages (message_id, message, sender_id, time_sent, time_read, conversation_id) 
VALUES ('','$reply','$user_id', NOW(), '', '$conversation_id')");   

    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ap_conversations SET time = NOW() WHERE conversation_id = '$conversation_id'");

    }
}
```

And also at the same time activate this Ajax script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reply').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: "system/sars_system.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            user_id: $('input[name="user_id"]').val(),
            message: $('input[name="message"]').val(),
            conversation_id: $('input[name="conversation_id"]').val(),
            sarssystem: $('input[name="sarssystem"]').val()
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(responseText){
            $('#out').html(responseText);
        }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Which is slightly further down on the same page which then should process this PHP script from a separate page:

```
require 'start.php';

    $user_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $conversation_id = $_POST['conversation_id'];
    $sarssystem = $_POST['sarssystem'];

if($message == 'hello'){
    $sarsreply = 'hey, how are you?';
}

mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ap_messages (message_id, message, sender_id, time_sent, time_read, conversation_id) 
VALUES ('','$sarsreply','0', DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL 5 SECOND), '', '$conversation_id')");

mysqli_close($conn);
```

The first section seems to work for posting the users reply although the automatic reply doesn't seem to be adding to the database which leads me to believe that the script isn't being run? Is there a problem with my Ajax or my PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clickI don't think you can do it in this way.

You must understand that when you click on 'Send Message', the event priority is your form action. So as you say you can post the data.

Because of this your click event will not fire for your supposed ajax call.

In my opinion the best you can do in this situation is try to handle both events with an ajax call.

Put your first php script which handle the insert in his own file, as you did for the 'system/sars_system.php'.

Make a ajax call to this file and insert the data in DB. It is important that if the data is successfully posted that you will do:

```
echo json_encode('success')

or (in this case)

echo 'success'
```

When you get a successful response from the server you will make the second ajax call to 'system/sars_system.php'

If you find this explanation not clear enough then here is a rough example on how you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reply').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/file',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {param1: 'value1'},
        })
        .done(function() {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/path/to/file',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {param1: 'value1'},
            })
            .done(function() {
                console.log("success");
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            })

        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
    });
 });
```

NOTE there are also other solution for this but this will be eay for you to implement.

I hope this will help you to go on with your work.

Comment: How can I check if the response was a success and run the second PHP file ?

Comment: I will now update my question to make this a little bit more clear for you. So please give me 5 min to do that.

Comment: I seem to be getting a syntax error with this script showing at the second line from the bottom?

Comment: Did you copy the ajax call from here? Maybe you have a typo or I have it. Please re-check and if still remain the same tell me which error you are getting.

Comment: Check also if you have '$('#reply').click(function(){' and NOT '$('#reply').submit(function(){'

Comment: Yeah I have updated using the `click` function and am still getting a syntax error showing on the `)};` second from bottom :S strange

Comment: I have reformatted ajax call again, what you are getting is a syntax error which means that a bracket is missing . Try now. Over 10 minutes I must go to the birthday of my sun, so if I don't answer I am not yet back. But when I will come back I will see if you have posted some message in here.